# In a recyclerview how to determine the radio button clicked is from the same radio group in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, radio-button, radio-group

I have a `RadioGroup` with 4 `RadioButtons` inside a `RecyclerView`.
RecyclerView adapter goes like this

```
    class QuestionRecyclerAdapter(var number:Int, val context: Context, val quesions: List<Question>,val qnADao: QnADao) : RecyclerView.Adapter<QuestionRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
        lateinit var question:Question
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

            return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.question_single_item, parent, false));
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {

            return quesions.size;
        }
         fun updateNumber(number: Int){
            this.number = number
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

            question = quesions[position]
            holder.textTestQuestion.text = ""+(number+position)+" "+ question.question;
            holder.answerFirst.text = "a. "+ question.answers?.get(0).toString()
            holder.answerSecond.text = "b. "+ question.answers?.get(1).toString()
            holder.answerThird.text = "c. "+ question.answers?.get(2).toString()
            holder.answerFourth.text = "d. "+ question.answers?.get(3).toString()   

            holder.radio_group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(object : RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener{
                override fun onCheckedChanged(group: RadioGroup?, checkedId: Int) {
                    when(checkedId){
                        R.id.answerFirst -> {
                            question.rightAnswer=0
                        }
                        R.id.answerSecond -> {
                            question.rightAnswer=1
                        }
                        R.id.answerThird -> {
                            question.rightAnswer=2
                        }
                        R.id.answerFourth -> {
                            question.rightAnswer=3
                        }
                    }

        }


        class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)  {
            val textTestQuestion = view.test_text_question
            val answerFirst = view.answerFirst
            val answerSecond = view.answerSecond
            val answerThird = view.answerThird
            val answerFourth = view.answerFourth
            val radio_group = view.radioGrp


        }
    }
```

`question_single_item.xml` is like this

```
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/first"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:checked="false"
            android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/second"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:checked="false"
            android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/third"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:checked="false"
            android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/fourth"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:checked="false"
            android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
            android:textSize="14dp" />
    </RadioGroup>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the recyclerview I am populating almost 100s of data and so there are 100 radio groups with 100*4 radio buttons. So I need to find out if the same radio buttons in a same radio group is selected or not. In other words, I need to find out if the radio button(4 in a group) selected is from the same group or not. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: try using Hashmap its similar to key value pair it will help you to set each question as key

Comment: Do you want to know which radioButton in a radioGroup isChecked?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use hash map on the behalf of every click of radio button in the same radio group 
This problem is mainly because of your Adapter object reusing.

So what you should do is, You should store the selected item some how and you should check and update when ever it called getView method in the view.

here is some code for refrence:please follow and let me know :

public class CustomArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

```
private Context context;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;

public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;

}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_questions, parent,false);
        holder.textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.radioGroup1 = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        holder.radio0 = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        holder.radio1 = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        holder.radio2 = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        holder.radio3 = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radio3);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder =(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.textView1.setText(data.get(position).get("questions"));
    holder.radio0.setText(data.get(position).get("op1"));
    holder.radio1.setText(data.get(position).get("op2"));
    holder.radio2.setText(data.get(position).get("op3"));
    holder.radio3.setText(data.get(position).get("op4"));

    HashMap<Integer,String> radioMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    radioMap.put(holder.radio0.getId(),holder.radio0.getText().toString());
    radioMap.put(holder.radio1.getId(),holder.radio1.getText().toString());
    radioMap.put(holder.radio2.getId(),holder.radio2.getText().toString());
    radioMap.put(holder.radio3.getId(),holder.radio3.getText().toString());

    holder.radioGroup1.setTag(radioMap);
    holder.radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            HashMap<Integer,String> data = (HashMap<Integer,String>) group.getTag();
            Toast.makeText(context,data.get(checkedId),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

class ViewHolder{
    TextView textView1;
    RadioGroup radioGroup1;
    RadioButton radio0;
    RadioButton radio1;
    RadioButton radio2;
    RadioButton radio3;
}
```

}